# How to print a line which first number is bigger than given parameter?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm learning bash still and so I want to make a shell script called myscript.sh.
If I specify a threshold like myscript.sh 5 < text.txt
I want it to only print the lines which first collumn is bigger than 5.

My text.txt file is of this structure:

```
5 15:00 email@email.com 
3 14:00 email@email2.com
8 13:00 email@email.com
```

my code is

```
NUMBER=$1
awk -F' ' '$1>NUMBER{ print $0 }'
```

but it still prints everything and if instead of NUMBER I enter any number it works perfectly

I want the output to be if I write myscript.sh 3 < text.txt

```
5 15:00 email@email.com
8 13:00 email@email.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use -v option to pass variable

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v NUMBER=$1 '{ if ($1> NUMBER) print $0 }'
```

Comment: Thanks this pestered me for hours.

Comment: Should be `awk -v number="$1" '$1 > number'`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the variable `NUMBER` is not set and therefore `$1>NUMBER` always evaluates to `true` for a number larger than `0`. You need to pass the variable to the [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) script:

```
awk '$1>NUMBER{ print $0 }' NUMBER="$1" data.txt
```